# sending to soap not worinkg

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I have android code which has two integers variables  getting from HashMap Key , value .

i'm trying to pass these two variables to SOAP web service but nothing happened .

notes 1: I'm sure my WebService code is working and entering the right data to database , i have tested it .

note 2 : FROM debug shows that "SID" and "status" has right values .

but the problem in sending these values to SOAP .

FULL SOAP code in android Activity :

```
sumbit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> mapEntry : checkBoxState
                    .entrySet()) {
                int SID = mapEntry.getKey();
                int status = mapEntry.getValue();

                Toast.makeText(context,
                        String.valueOf(SID) + String.valueOf(status),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                            METHOD_NAME);
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                            URL);
                    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
                    pi.setName("SID");
                    pi.setValue(SID);
                    pi.setType(Integer.class);
                    request.addProperty(pi);

                    PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
                    pi2.setName("status");
                    pi2.setValue(status);
                    pi2.setType(Integer.class);
                    request.addProperty(pi2);

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
```

FULL webService Method Code :

```
public void insertApsentData(int SID , int status ) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, ReflectiveOperationException, Throwable{

// Make new Connection to database .
Dbconnection NewConnect = new Dbconnection();
Connection con = NewConnect.MakeConnect();
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

// this i'm usre is working fine 
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO apsent SET course_id=1, teacher_id= 1 , class_id= 3 , interval_id= 5 , day_id = 1 , APSSENT_DATE = CURdate() ,state = " + status + ", student_id = " + SID +" ,school_id = 1;");//called the procedure


     }
```

Comment: When sending these values to soap , soap actually doesn't send it to webservice method " insertApsentData ", there is no error log appearing

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before. Have you tried generating the wsdl using [eclipse?](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf)(see page 6). This tool generates the client code for a webservice and makes it easy to call something like

```
ServiceProxy.insertApsentData(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some project Folders are closed , i reopened it and it's works now .